# Yesterday it said that there were 200 thousand questions, now back to 199 thousand, how come?

Tags: bug, questions, statistics

Yesterday I looked at that thing on the main AskUbuntu site which tells you how many questions there are on the site, and it said 200 thousand and something, but today it says that there are currently 199,815, how come the sudden drop in questions? Were loads of them deleted or something? Or was it just a bug, and actually there were never over 200 thousand questions?

Comment: Two hundred questions might be a bit of a stretch, but up till 11 hours ago, at least 45 questions were deleted.

Comment: @muru: Must have been some sort of a site glitch then because I know what I saw.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a very dangerous monster that prowls the site at night, usually around 3 o'clock UTC she comes out. Half shark and half feline she roams with a waddling sidekick. Clearing the site of all old, downvoted, and unanswered posts.

[image]

### The roombacat!

Okay, so there is no cat, or duck. At least, I've never seen them...

There *is* a roomba though. And it *does* delete things. Specifically things matching [these criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).

Comment: All it needs is a laser...

Comment: No 2! 2 lasers are better than 1.